# Popular .NET Compact Framework open source applications / components

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

In my company I am responsible for the development of a .NET CF application which runs on top of Windows CE. We have invested much time in the development of a GUI framework, a top-level design which handles authorizations and navigation on the device, a IoC customer, ...

Now I was wondering if there are any other projects which show kind of best practices (for example what the prefered way of GUI drawing is).

In the following there are some which I know:

- [UI Framework for .NET Compact Framework 3.5](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/uiframework)
- [Project Resistance](http://resistance.codeplex.com/)
- [Amplite Application Port from IPhone*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355030.aspx)
- [Several twitter clients](http://blogs.msdn.com/lokeuei/archive/2009/04/16/windows-mobile-twitter-apps.aspx)
- [CaveMen from LightWorkGames*](http://www.lightworksgames.com/blog/entries.aspx?groupid=0c172efd-d578-4ecd-8efa-12b92aec732f)

What applications / components do you know?

* actually not a application, but definetely worth to take a look

Comment: Isn't this a community wiki post?

Comment: The Amplit atricle you reference is absolute garbage.  MSDN's quality bar has gone way down.  It doesn't talk at all about how to port Objective C to WinMo, not does it even give reasonable examples in the code it does present.  For example look at their "simple" example of getting/setting a registry value.  It's a WTF all by itself, and unfortunately code snippets like these get copied into production code by junior developers.

Answer (score 3):

There are always the ever-popular:

- [Smart Device Framework](http://smartdeviceframework.com) (old and new)
- [OpenNETCF.IoC Framework](http://ioc.codeplex.com)
- [OpenNETCF Serial Library](http://serial.codeplex.com)
- [OpenNETCF Telephony component](http://tapi.codeplex.com)
- [OpenNETCF RAS component](http://rascf.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I know I always like to take a look at the [SDF 1.x](http://www.opennetcf.com/FreeSoftware/SDF1x/tabid/91/Default.aspx) source code for reference. Though, it is not up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Silvermoon](http://silvermoon.codeplex.com/)